# Looking for a more condensed method of assigning values by using arrays and fixed ranges

Tags: array, vba, excel

I currently have a Template Workbook set up that has charts and graphs updating when new data is plugged into the Data Tables.
The Data Tables are fixed ranges, and won't change.

The Macro is within the Template Workbook, which is why the below code doesn't set variables for each of the worksheets within the Template Workbook, and `Code Names` are used for each Worksheet name.

I know the below code is a very basic array code, and works.  However, Is there a more condensed way to perform this array macro?
I have researched, but can't seem to find an example of multiple ranges and assigning values from the `Source Workbook - Multiple Worksheets` to the `Template Workbook - Multiple Worksheets`.

```
Sub Main()

'Turn off screen updates and automatic calculations
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim wbDataSource As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbDataSource = Workbooks("Segment Trends Data.xlsx")
    
    For Each ws In wbDataSource.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Index <> 1 Then
                Dim Data(13) As Variant
                Data(0) = Worksheets("Report1").Range("A1").Value2
                Data(1) = Worksheets("Report1").Range("A5:H11").Value2
                Data(2) = Worksheets("Report2").Range("A1").Value2
                Data(3) = Worksheets("Report2").Range("A5:H11").Value2
                Data(4) = Worksheets("Report3").Range("A1").Value2
                Data(5) = Worksheets("Report3").Range("A5:H11").Value2
                Data(6) = Worksheets("Report4").Range("A1").Value2
                Data(7) = Worksheets("Report4").Range("A5:H11").Value2
                Data(8) = Worksheets("Report5").Range("A1").Value2
                Data(9) = Worksheets("Report5").Range("A5:H11").Value2
                Data(10) = Worksheets("Report6").Range("A1").Value2
                Data(11) = Worksheets("Report6").Range("A5:H11").Value2
                Data(12) = Worksheets("Report7").Range("A1").Value2
                Data(13) = Worksheets("Report7").Range("A5:H11").Value2
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    
    wbDataSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    With wsTTLUSCYTD
        .Range("A1").Value2 = Data(0)
        .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = Data(1)
    End With
    
    With wsCintiCYTD
        .Range("A1").Value2 = Data(2)
        .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = Data(3)
    End With
    
    With wsCOLCYTD
        .Range("A1").Value2 = Data(4)
        .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = Data(5)
    End With
    
    With wsDaytonCYTD
        .Range("A1").Value2 = Data(6)
        .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = Data(7)
    End With
    
    With wsIndyCYTD
        .Range("A1").Value2 = Data(8)
        .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = Data(9)
    End With
    
    With wsLouisCYTD
        .Range("A1").Value2 = Data(10)
        .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = Data(11)
    End With
    
    With wsCoreMktCYTD
        .Range("A1").Value2 = Data(12)
        .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = Data(13)
    End With
    
    Calculate
    
    Dim TemplatePath As String
        TemplatePath = "C:\Users\cday\OneDrive - udfinc.com\Budgeting Presentation_Working Files\"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=TemplatePath & "Segment Trends - CYTD - Budget Template" & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52

'Turn screen updates and automatic calculations back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Using Debug.Print, the data is pulling from the `wbDataSource` worksheets within the Loop.
[image: Debug.Print]

Comment: Does this code work for you?  There are a few problems that jump out to me right away: you are opening up `wbDataSource`, but when you're pulling data from the `ReportX` worksheets, you're not getting data from the `wbDataSource` workbook. The data is actually coming from whatever your `ActiveWorkbook` is currently (and it's **not** `wbDataSource`!). Also, you are looping through all the worksheets in a workbook, but it's not necessary because you are explicitly specifying which worksheet's data is copied to a `Data` array slot. Assigning the other sheet objects (`wsCintiCYTD`) is not shown.

Comment: @PeterT Yes, this works for me.  I'm not sure why you're saying the data is not coming from `wbDataSource`, because I am using `For each ws in `wbDataSurce.worksheets`, `With ws` to the the `.value2` of each range.  I specified the worksheet by it's name: `Worksheets("Report1").range` `Worksheets("Report2").range`, etc..

Comment: @PeterT I didn't need to assign the other sheet objects, that are receiving the data, because the module is within that Workbook with `Code Names`

Comment: In your `For Each ws In wbDataSource.Worksheets` loop, your only reference to anything in `wbDataSource` is when you are checking `.Index` because that is explicitly using the `With ws` clause. So your reference is really `If ws.Index <> 1 Then`. Inside that loop, there are no other references to `ws`. Also, all of your `.Value2` references are accessing the ***currently active worksheet***, NOT necessarily `wbDataSource`. Simply opening another workbook doesn't guarantee to make it active. And nothing in your `With ws` clause is used for any of the `.Value2` references.

Comment: Additionally, let's say your `wbDataSource` workbook has 12 worksheets. Your loop to set the `Data` array accessing the exactly same data 12 times, completely regardless of how many worksheets there are, or what is on those worksheets. There's no reason to loop since you're explicitly getting 14 `.Value2` values from very specific worksheets. So the loop is not necessary.

Comment: @PeterT I guess I don't understand what you're saying.  When I use `Debug.Print`, it's pulling the values from the `wbDataSource`.  The Loop is going through each worksheet within the `wbDataSource` except Sheet 1.  I added a picture to the original post

Comment: @PeterT In regards to not needing the loop. I get what you're saying, but then I loose my reference to the `wbDataSource`.  So how would I go about getting those Data Values?

Comment: If you are just trying to condense the code to make it more readable, you could consider using [bracket notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137344/61846) for reading your cell value. Building off of PeterT's answer, you could then condense the first line of the with statement to `Data(0) = [Report1!A1]`. Note that the `value2` is implied here, if you want the range you would have to add a `set` to the beginning of that statement.

Answer (score 2):

The comment discussion in the original post directly relate to the differences between the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`. While you code may indeed work, it's not a guarantee. [This reference](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/activeworkbook-thisworkbook/) (and [this one](https://analystcave.com/vba-tip-day-activeworkbook-vs-thisworkbook/)) have good explanations to illustrate the differences between how you reference a workbook and why you should always pay specific attention to references (whether it's to the `Workbook` or `Worksheet` or `Range`).

As explained in the comments, because you specifically identify the worksheet for all the `.Value2` data, you don't need to loop through all the worksheets. This will reduce the setup of your array to

```
Dim wbDataSource As Workbook
Set wbDataSource = Workbooks("Segment Trends Data.xlsx")

Dim Data(13) As Variant
With wbDataSource
    Data(0) = .Worksheets("Report1").Range("A1").Value2
    Data(1) = .Worksheets("Report1").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    Data(2) = .Worksheets("Report2").Range("A1").Value2
    Data(3) = .Worksheets("Report2").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    Data(4) = .Worksheets("Report3").Range("A1").Value2
    Data(5) = .Worksheets("Report3").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    Data(6) = .Worksheets("Report4").Range("A1").Value2
    Data(7) = .Worksheets("Report4").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    Data(8) = .Worksheets("Report5").Range("A1").Value2
    Data(9) = .Worksheets("Report5").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    Data(10) = .Worksheets("Report6").Range("A1").Value2
    Data(11) = .Worksheets("Report6").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    Data(12) = .Worksheets("Report7").Range("A1").Value2
    Data(13) = .Worksheets("Report7").Range("A5:H11").Value2
End With
```

Notice that I've changed the `With` clause to reference the `wbDataSource` workbook so that's it's very clear where all your data is coming from.

The code you've written actually doesn't need an array, in fact the array obscures what the code is really trying to do. What exactly is `Data(0)` or `Data(11)`? You might find it tedious, but I would more clearly define what information all those variables hold. As an example

```
Dim reportTitle As String
Dim reportDescription As String
Dim regionNumber As Long
Dim regionManager As String

With wbDataSource
    reportTitle = .Worksheets("Report1").Range("A1").Value2
    reportDescription = .Worksheets("Report1").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    regionNumber = .Worksheets("Report2").Range("A1").Value2
    regionManager = .Worksheets("Report2").Range("A5:H11").Value2
    ...
End With
```

Now when you come back to make an update to your code in six months, you don't have to remember what each of those array slots actually means.

Finally, getting back to the original question of your post, there's no magic or easy way to make the assignments to multiple destination worksheets. You've already defined the code names for each of the sheets, so the VBA you have is about as simple as you can make it. I still recommend the change to more descriptive variable names to make it clear which data you are copying to the destination worksheets.

```
With wsTTLUSCYTD
    .Range("A1").Value2 = reportTitle
    .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = reportDescription
End With

With wsCintiCYTD
    .Range("A1").Value2 = regionNumber
    .Range("A5:H11").Value2 = regionManager
End With
```